# how to put in variable a promise http (service angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

i have i big problems, i want to put a service in variable in my controller

but there is a probleme, when a call a service with a http inside it give me a $$state object (impossible to take the value of this one)

this is my code service and controller

```
routeAppControllers.factory('ServiceSms', function($http,Token) {

var key = Token.CreateToken()

var myService = {

    async: function() {

        var data = 'token=' + encodeURIComponent(key);
        var promise =  $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'PhpFunction/getsms.php',
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            cache: true
        })

            .then(function(data) {

                // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                //  console.log(data.data);
                // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                return data.data;
            })

        // Return the promise to the controller
        return promise;
    }
};
return myService;
```

});

inside the controller

```
    routeAppControllers.controller('customersCtrl',['$scope','$rootScope','$filter','$log','$http','$cookies','$timeout','$uibModal','ServiceGetData','sha256','ServiceSms', function($scope,$rootScope, $filter, $log, $http,$cookies, $timeout, $uibModal,ServiceGetData,sha256,ServiceSms ) {

          var e =  ServiceSms.async();
        console.log(e);
}])
```

reponse : Object { $$state: Object }

but

for my service Token i have no problems to get it in a variable because i don't have the http inside

```
    routeAppControllers.factory('Token', function(sha256) {

   var myService =   {

       CreateToken: function () {

           var date = new Date();

           var time = date.getTime().toString();

           var string = time;

           var key = sha256.convertToSHA256(string);

           return key;

       }


   }

   return myService;

});
```

i m stuck i realy need my var e =  ServiceSms.async(); in my controller , but i don't know how

please some one can help me

thanks in advance

EDIT

i put the service like you but i have always the probleme for my var e , always $$state object with your code , me i need something like this

```
var e = ServiceSms.async().then(function(data) {

       console.log(data.data); // return me this one Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 1460 de plus… ] good 
       return data.data; // i want get with var e outside of service because i need this table 
    });
    console.log(e); /// Object { $$state: Object } no good
```

Comment: It returns a promise, so you can do `ServiceSms.async().then(function(data) { // do something with the returned data });`

Answer (score 0):

That's shown because at the time `ServiceSms`  response assign the to variable, promise is not resolved.Its still resolving. service return the http to controller but the promise is still resolving. That's why `$$state` display in the console.

One thing you can do is remove the promise from the service and add the promise to the controller. That way you can catch the response after the promise is captured

```
routeAppControllers.factory('ServiceSms', function($http, Token) {
    var key = Token.CreateToken()
    var myService = {
        async: function() {
            var data = 'token=' + encodeURIComponent(key);
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'PhpFunction/getsms.php',
                data: data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                cache: true
            })
            return promise;
        }
    };
    return myService;
})
routeAppControllers.controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$filter', '$log', '$http', '$cookies', '$timeout', '$uibModal', 'ServiceGetData', 'sha256', 'ServiceSms', function($scope, $rootScope, $filter, $log, $http, $cookies, $timeout, $uibModal, ServiceGetData, sha256, ServiceSms) {
    ServiceSms.async().then(function(data) {
        var e = data.data;
    });
    console.log(e);
}])
```

Edited

```
var e ;
 ServiceSms.async().then(function(data) {

       console.log(data.data); // return me this one Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, 1460 de plus… ] good 
        e  = data.data; // i want get with var e outside of service because i need this table 
       console.log(e)
    });
```

Comment: thanks sir but i have one problem yet , i need to get outside of my service beacause i need this table in my controller check my edit please i put your code in mine

Comment: u misunderstood the concept of the promise. since javascript asynchronous it does not wait until the response returns that's why console showing that. you need to add the console log inside the promise `then`. if you want to assign the data to javascript variable then instead of returning the data from promise assign the data inside the promise check the updated answer